# Recaman with recursion

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

```
lst = []
def recaman(n):
  #print lst
  if n == 1:
    lst.append(n)
    return 1
  else:
    a = recaman(n-1)
    am = a - n
    ap = a + n
    if am > 0 and am not in lst:
      lst.append(am)
      return am
    else:
      lst.append(ap)
      return ap
  #print lst
  #lst.append(temp)   
#print recaman(1)
#print recaman(2)
#print recaman(3)
#print recaman(4)
#print recaman(5)
print recaman(6)
#13
```

This might be easy question for you but I couldn't find the explanation of this:
If I print just `recaman(6)` The output is `13` which is true, however if i print `recaman(5)` and `recaman(6)` at the same time, the output is `7 and 11` which should have been `7 and 13`. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the list is being defined globally, so after `recaman` is called, the next call to the function produces unexpected results because the list still has items in it:

```
print(recaman(5)) # 7
print(lst) # [1, 3, 6, 2, 7]
```

### Solution

There are many possible solutions, but a simple, elegant one (in my opinion), is to make the `recaman` function take a list as a parameter. This list can then be passed around in the recursive calls. Initially you would call it with an empty list. So the final code becomes:

```
def recaman(n, lst):
  if n == 1:
    lst.append(n)
    return 1
  else:
    a = recaman(n-1, lst)
    am = a - n
    ap = a + n
    if am > 0 and am not in lst:
      lst.append(am)
      return am
    else:
      lst.append(ap)
      return ap

print(recaman(5, [])) # 7
print(recaman(6, [])) # 13
```